# Is it answering a question if you tell them their premise is wrong?

Tags: discussion, answers

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940855/jlabel-not-positioning-correctly) appeared yesterday, language content unimportant. I can sum it up as a simple language-agnostic problem.

> I am not sure why X happens. I know I should be doing Y, but I wanted to try something without Y.

Y is a standard practice, but the OP has explicitly said he is not using Y.

I respond with the following.

> This is why X happens.

Another user replies, later, pointing out that my answer is "dross" and that:

> Not using Y is a bad idea. You should be using Y. Here is your entire code written with Y.

I have been under the impression the entire time on Stack Overflow that you should answer the asked question. Questions in native [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) typically should not have the answer of *Have you tried JQuery* even though it is technically a valid answer, because it doesn't answer the asked question, rather it provides a workaround that ignores the actual question.

Have I been misinterpreting this the entire time? Should I be addressing the overarching issue or just the question?

Comment: This is going to be context specific, and simply cannot be answered in the abstract.  If someone says, "I know that I should just turn the doorknob when I want to open the door, but I was wondering how to open the door using explosives, just for fun.  How do I do that instead."  you simply don't answer the question asked, because it's irresponsible to do so.  But in some cases, where it's not a problem to explain a less than ideal solution, it's not actually detrimental.  Context.

Comment: If you are contracted to do work X, you should do work X and keep checking your bank a/c.   If you are an employee, you should engage with your peers and managers if you feel that something is being done incorrectly.  If you are an unpaid volunteer, ask/state/ague what you want!  What can they do, withhold payment or fire you?

Comment: @MartinJames Wait, you mean Imaginary Internet Points *aren't* more important than money in my bank account?  Since when?

Comment: Don't confuse "is or isn't an answer" with "is or isn't a *useful* answer". Not useful answers are certainly allowed.

Comment: Not an answer, and not implying this is a dupe, but you might find some useful / related questions in this search on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=x+y+problem

Comment: Side note, I don't see the word "dross" anywhere on the linked question but I do see a link that answers this question! :) [is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: Now I really want to open a door with explosives...

Comment: @TinyGiant 1. Take the explosive in your hand 2. Knock on the door 3. ??? 4. Profit.

Comment: [Obligatory reference to "Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?"](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Comment: ***Absolutely!*** Remember that Stack Overflow is not a Help Desk. You are not just solving one person's problem; you are solving *everyone's* problem. Even if the person who originally asked the question has some unusual situation that requires them to do things the wrong way (and usually they don't, they're just confused), most future Googlers will not be under any such constraints and would therefore benefit most from your answer proposing an alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the answer is, "don't do it *this* way", then that's *still* an answer.  Unless the OP is hard-constrained into doing it that specific way, then saying that their original premise is incorrect is often the *right* thing to do.

In the context of "should I address the overarching issue", think of it like a doctor prescribing medication or giving advice otherwise.  By only prescribing medicine, you're addressing a symptom and not really fixing the root cause, leading to reduced care.  By prescribing medicine *and* providing timely and appropriate advice, you've addressed the symptom and have given the patient an opportunity to address the root cause.

Comment: I know [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=profile) has given these types of answers ("don't do it this way")before and they have been well received. I'm trying to find some example from a few months back that i remember... but he answers too many questions for me to trace back

Answer (score 4):

I would consider asking in comments about changing constraints before providing an answer that violated assumptions/constraints/premises.  Sometimes as an asker, getting into the "why's" of a premise would be lengthy and detract from the core question.  In an effort to be succinct, someone may not attempt to justify a premise, but explicitly outline constraints.  There are also occasions someone generally wants to do something quick and dirty, and there's an appropriate time for that as well.

Approach it in a constructive manner, rather than destructive.  Don't challenge the premise by pointing out the premise is bad, but instead offer a solution outside the premise:

> If you aren't require to use Office interop libraries, I could provide a an example using EPPlus open source library.

If you can't offer an alternative to the goal, it's hard to justify shooting someone's premise down.  In other words, if you just tell someone not to do something, but you haven't separated out what their goal is and offer even a conceptual idea of a different way to obtain that goal, then it's not an answer.

You can usually tell from the question, some rough idea of the experience level of the asker.  It may be clear they are going about it the wrong way and are just generally confused.  If the focus of the question is on some goal, then an answer that obtains that goal is likely to be well received.  If not useful to the asker, may be useful to a future visitor.  In such a case I'd probably go ahead and post an answer.

On the other hand, if someone is very explicit in laying out constraints, then they're probably more experienced.  Possibly in the absence of those constraints they'd have a solution on their own, and they are seeking other ideas because the constraints create a challenge.

Even experienced devs sometimes imply some constraints they didn't intend to.  In one question I asked about creating a Dictionary on multiple constraints, but it wasn't clear to the commenter why I didn't consider Tuples.  The answer that resulted ended up being the best.

Lastly, don't be argumentative or adversarial in challenging a premise.  You just detract from the core question.  There's nothing worse than taking the time to lay out constraints, and then getting into a long debate via comments.  Especially if you are debugging, throwing something together one off, or are in the context of very old legacy software, you may have odd constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing at the end of the day is that the questioner finds *an* answer that resolves the question. If there's a very strong persuasive argument about why the questioner should use a different approach, then it makes sense for that approach to be suggested. One-line "have you tried" answers are unproductive in any context. However, if the recommendation includes sample code or multiple paragraphs about why the problem can be most efficiently or elegantly addressed via the recommended method, then it's not a bad answer whether or not the questioner is willing to change their approach.